# Docker scale and elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

The public docker image for elasticsearch is on docker hub
https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/

If i defined my own docker-compose file with elasticsearch, how would i scale up elasticsearch so that the ports don't collide?

```
     version: '2'

    services:
      elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:latest
        ports:
          - "9200:9200"
          - "9300:9300"
  kibana:
    image: kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
```

How could i scale this up, similar to the command below?

```
docker-compose scale elasticsearch=3
```

I am running docker beta for mac version 1.12.

Thanks,
Shane.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the ports don't collide, we should use "automatic port mapping" with docker-compose.yml as below:

```
version: '2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:latest
    ports:
      - 9200
      - 9300
```

So Docker will automatically map ports `9200` and `9300` to random ports in range 32xxx.

Comment: If i do not expose port, then kibana fails.

Comment: Because Kibana connect Elasticsearch on port 9200. But In this case, ES work on port 32xxx. So you have to change Kibana's config file.

Comment: i found a good example here http://blog.codingtimes.com/docker-using-compose-to-scale-up-elasticsearch-cluster/

Comment: @shanelee sorry, I have moved the post from codingtimes.com [here](https://kgiann78.github.io/docker/elasticsearch/2016/12/17/Docker-using-compose-to-scale-up-elasticsearch-cluster.html) because our blog is about to close. Sorry for the inconvenience!